# How to get exact position of elements which are in the same row but in different columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, position

Suppose I have the following data set named as `dat`.

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
id  v1  v2
1   5   0.5
1   4   0.5
1   6   0.5
2   2   0.2
2   3   0.2
2   7   0.2')
```

My plan is to split data by `id` and do some calculations on the other columns. For instance, in computing `var3`, the code should check the corresponding values of `v1` and `v2` should be in the same row. The following is what I tried.

```
dat2 <- list()
var3 <- list()
mtr <- data.frame(id=NA,var3=NA)

for (i in seq_along(unique(dat$id))){
  dat2[[i]] <- subset(dat,dat$id==unique(dat$id)[i])
  var3[[i]] <- dat2[[i]]$v1/dat2[[i]]$v2    # Here is my problem!
  mtr[i,1] <- dat2[[i]]$id
  mtr[i,2] <- var3[[i]]
}
```

The expected output is `mtr`:

```
1 10
1 8
1 12
2 10
2 15
2 35
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sorry! Corrected now!

Comment: Yeah, it gives `NA`. But what I need is to get `var3 = v1/v2`.

Comment: It would be great to have an expected output for crosschecking

Comment: For division, it is elementwise, not sure why you need to match i.e. `dat$v1/dat$v2`

Comment: You created `mtr`, but all your calculation results are saved in `var3`? Can you show your expected results?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include lines. Now included!

Answer (score 0):

Division is elementwise.  So, it doesn't need any matching for different 'id'

```
dat$V3 <- dat$v1/dat$v2
```

-output

```
dat
#  id v1  v2 V3
#1  1  5 0.5 10
#2  1  4 0.5  8
#3  1  6 0.5 12
#4  2  2 0.2 10
#5  2  3 0.2 15
#6  2  7 0.2 35
```

If it needs to subsetted, use `split` afterwards into a `list`

```
outlst <- split(dat, dat$id)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's true. However, the data should be subsetted in my case and then I will use them in the subsequent work.

Comment: @Gada You can split afterwards.  Doing an operation on a for loop when it is not intended is not efficient